# Update values in all columns (up to 30) of multiple (up to 100) rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table

[image]

I need to update all values in multiple rows(let's say in 70 of them) depending on `id` in `someTable`. The information about rows which should be updated I should get from `excel file`. So how should I update those values? Is this the only way (repeat the same code for all rows)?

```
UPDATE someTable
    SET col1 = newVal1,
        col2 = newVal2,
        ...
        col30 = newVal30
    WHERE id = 1

............

UPDATE someTable
    SET col1 = newVal70-1,
        col2 = newVal70-2,
        ...
        col30 = newVal70-30
    WHERE id = 70
```

Comment: Yes, that is the only way. That's not very normalized, having 30 identical columns in a table. They should be unpivoted into rows

Comment: Please don't use imaged for data... use formatted text.

Comment: Where do the new values come from - are these hard coded, from another table or also the Excel file?

Comment: The code for the first `update` is not consistent with the image.

Comment: @Stu there is a table that already exists in DB. There are 1000-s of rows. i need to update some of those rows with the new values (except id fo course) from excel file.

Comment: @Charliefacewhat do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

You might find it convenient to express this using `values`:

```
UPDATE someTable
    SET col1 = newVal - 1,
        col2 = newVal - 2,
        ...
        col30 = newVal30 - 30
    FROM SomeTable st JOIN
         (VALUES (1, newVal1),
                 (2, newVal2),
                 . . .
         ) v(id, newVal)
         ON st.id = v.id;
```

That is, you can do this with a single update.

Note:  This looks rather suspicious as an `update` process.  I suspect that another tables structure with one row per `id` and `col` (i.e. 30 rows per `id`) would be more appropriate.

Comment: And what if there are more than 30 rows to update? 100 or even more?

Comment: @JunDev You already know the answer to that question as it is the same issue as your previous question.